# Birth of chaos due to nonautonomous perturbation

Tags: ds.dynamical-systems, manifolds, symbolic-dynamics, chaos

Let $\sigma, b>0$. I want to study the dynamics of the map
$$ T \colon \mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{S}^1 \times \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{S}^1 \times \mathbb{R}$$ such that
$$T_{\sigma,b}(n,\theta,y) = (\theta+by,\frac{y}{2}+\sigma g(n) \sin(2\pi\theta)) $$
where
$$ g(n) = n  \pmod 2 $$
This map is obtained by periodically kicking the autonomous  dynamical system $T_{0,b}.$

We are interested in characterizing the pullback attractor of $T_{\sigma,b}$ for all values of parameters. Numerical simulations showed that for small values of parameters the pullback attractor is an invariant closed curve. What is interesting, though, is that if I increase $\sigma$ (or $b$),  the invariant curve is broken and we see the generation of a chaotic attractor.
I was able  to prove the existence for small value of $b,\sigma$ of the invariant closed curve.
What I can not do is understand why such curve disappears in favour of a chaotic attractor.
In particular, I am looking for references helping me to answer the following questions:

$(1)$ what is the geometrical mechanism leading to the distruction of the invariant curve ;

$(2)$ How can one prove the existence of a chaotic attractor for some values of parameters and what are the mathematical properties an attractor must have to be considered chaotic.

Any help is very much appreciated

Comment: The map becomes autonomous when you consider its square. That would probably be a better way to look at it.

Comment: You mean you iterate it twice right? Is there any reference for this problem in the autonomous case?

Comment: I meant non-autonomous

Comment: Any non-autonomous result will be weaker of more complicated than the corresponding autonomous result. Since the two step version of your system is autonomous, it makes no sense to study the non-autonomous version.

Comment: Ok I get it. Of course also the second iterate undergoes a similar transition to chaotic behaviour. Do you think it is known what induces this transition and how to quantify it? In such case, could you provide any reference, please?

Comment: The closest maps I know (to the second iterate) are the Henon map and the Lozi map. Neither is a perfect comparison: Henon is more complicated in the first coordinate; and Lozi is discontinuous in the second coordinate.